# Center Icon inside a Round Container

Tags: flutter

I use the following code:

```
ClipOval(child: Material(
      color: const Color(0xffF6F6F6),
          child: InkWell(splashColor: Colors.black, // Splash color
           onTap: () {},
           child: const SizedBox(
           width: 120, height: 120, child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 96, color: Color(0xFF828A9E)))))),
```

However the Icon is slightly tilted to the right...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the icon with center widget

```
ClipOval(
  child: Material(
    color: const Color(0xffF6F6F6),
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.black, // Splash color
      onTap: () {},
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 120,
        height: 120,
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.person,
            size: 96,
            color: Color(0xFF828A9E),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```